# Why I can't verify these numbers?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I've a problem: I want to get some integers from a json file and then check there if there are equals to the current date/month. But I've this error:

```py
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'check_for_birthday'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baron_btjit4i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 168, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\baron_btjit4i\Desktop\Autrebot\Cogs\birthday.py", line 35, in check_for_birthday
    if member['month'] == curmonth:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My function:

```py
    @tasks.loop(seconds=1)
    async def check_for_birthday(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        curmonth = now.month
        curday = now.day
        guild = self.client.get_guild(guild_id)
        channel = self.client.get_channel(channel_id)
        
        with open(birthday_file, 'r') as f:
            var = jason.load(f)
            for member in var:
                if member['month'] == curmonth:
                    if member['day'] == curday:
                        try:
                            await self.client.get_user(member).send("Happy birthday!")
                        except:
                            pass
                        success = False
                        index = 0
                        while not success:
                            try:
                                await channel.send(f"Happy birthday to <@{member}>!")
                            except nextcord.Forbidden:
                                                    index += 1
                            except AttributeError:
                                index += 1
                            except IndexError:
                                # if the server has no channels, doesn't let the bot talk, or all vc/categories
                                pass
                            else:
                                success = True
```

My json file:

```json
{
    "712319703602692117": {
        "month": 12,
        "day": 12
    }
}
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `var` is a dictionary, `for member in var:` will iterate over its *keys*. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> `iter(d)`
>
> Return an iterator over the keys of the dictionary. This is a shortcut for `iter(d.keys())`.

So in your case, `member == "712319703602692117"`. Thus, `member['month']` is an error because strings can only be indexed by integers and slices, *not* other strings.

You can iterate over key/value pairs using [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
for key, member in var.items():
    ...
```

Here, `member == {"month": 12, "day": 12}`.

Comment: I've this error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

Comment: This means the input file is malformed. It has nothing to do with accessing keys or values of a dictionary.